# Partial Derivative term in the Gradient Descent Algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

I'm learning the "Machine Learning - Andrew Ng" course from Coursera. In the lesson called "Gradient Descent", I've found the formula a bit complicated. The theorem is consist of "**partial derivative**" term. 
The problem for me to understand the calculation of partial derivative term. Thus, later the term is calculated as  ​

> **1/m *
> ∑
> ​
> (h
> θ
> ​
> (x) − y(i)
> )²**

My question is, "How did the **1/2m** from the 'Cost Function' becomes **1/m** while calculating the partial derivative inside the **Gradient Descent** theorem?"

Comment: Please do no ask pure math questions in Stack Overflow, as this is a programming site.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'll consider such future questions into "math.stakexchage"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differentiation of `x²` is `2x`.
Similarly, differentiation of `∑​(h θ​(x) − y(i) )²` is `2 * ∑​(h θ​(x) − y(i) )`.
Therefore, differentiation of `1/2m * ∑​(h θ​(x) − y(i) )²` is `1/m * ∑​(h θ​(x) − y(i) )`.

Comment: Thank you for helping me to understand the term.